# Mapping BIGDECIMAL from Mongo, lack CONSTRUCTOR

Tags: json, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a problem when I want get a object from mongo with a BigDecimal field.

I have the next structure in mongo:

```
{
"_id":ObjectId("546b07420c74bf96c7c3cd5f"),
"accountId":"1",
"modelVersion":"seasonal_optimized",
"yearMonth":"20143",
   "income":{
        "unscaled":{
           "$numberLong":"68500"
         },
       "scale":2
      },
     "expense":{
         "unscaled":{
         "$numberLong":"125900"
      },
     "scale":2
     }
}
```

And the entity is :

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "forecasts")
public class Forecast {

    private String accountId;
    private LocalDate monthYear;
    private String modelVersion;
    private BigDecimal income;
    private BigDecimal expense;


}
```

and I'm trying retrieving a object from mongo, but I got the next error:

org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate java.math.BigDecimal using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments.

Anybody can help me?

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but I had the same issue using Spring data mongo and the aggregation framework.
Specifically when I want a BigDecimal as return type.

A possible workaround is to wrap your `BigDecimal` in a class and provide it as your return `OutPutType`, ie:

```
@Data
public class AverageTemperature {
    private BigDecimal averageTemperature;
}

@Override
public AverageTemperature averageTemperatureByDeviceIdAndDateRange(String deviceId, Date from, Date to) {
    final Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            match(
                Criteria.where("deviceId")
                    .is(deviceId)
                    .andOperator(
                        Criteria.where("time").gte(from),
                        Criteria.where("time").lte(to)
                    )
            ),
            group("deviceId")
                .avg("temperature").as("averageTemperature"),
            project("averageTemperature")
    );

    AggregationResults<AverageTemperature> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YourDocumentClass.class), AverageTemperature.class);
    List<AverageTemperature> mappedResults = result.getMappedResults();
    return (mappedResults != null ? mappedResults.get(0) : null);
}
```

In the example above the aggregation calculates the average temperature as BigDecimal.

Keep in mind that the default `BigDecimal` converter map it to a string in mongodb when saving. [mapping-conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-conversion)

Retrieving the document as is should not be a problem anymore with Spring data mongo, versions I used:

- `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE`
- `spring-data-mongodb:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE`
- `org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:jar:3.6.3`